# What is the equivalent to `span` using `lens`?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Let's say I have

```
data SumType = A | B | C

list = [A, B, B, A, C, A]

(as, rest) = span (\case A -> True; _ -> False) list
```

Assuming I have the prism `_A`, is there a way to write this more succinctly using `lens`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could say

```
(as, rest) = break (isn't _A) list
```

`isn't` is defined in [Control.Lens.Prism](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:isn-39-t). Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a corresponding function `is' p = not . isn't p`, although

```
(as, rest) = span (isRight . matching _A) list
```

would also work.

Comment: `Control.Lens.Fold.has` works as the negation of `isn't`.

Comment: Thanks! There seems to be `Control.Lens.Extras.is`